# isEnabled() always returns true - protractor

Tags: checkbox, protractor

there are couple of checkboxes. i am trying to test the first checkbox is enabled or disabled.

my html is -

```
<md-checkbox ng-change="$ctrl.onDnbStatusChange(result)" 
ng-disabled="result.status == 'Deny'" aria-label="Checkbox" 
ng-model="result.dnb" role="checkbox" 
class="ng-valid md-blueTheme-theme ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched 
ng-empty" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true" aria-checked="false" aria-invalid="false" 
disabled="disabled">
```

i am using this command to test it- the problem is, it always returns true even though the checkbox is disabled.

```
expect(element.all(by.model('result.dnb')).get(0).isEnabled()).toBe(false);
```

any suggestions.

thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have this exact checkbox matched by `element.all(by.model('result.dnb')).get(0)`? Could it be there are other elements with this model? Thanks.

Comment: i am sure it is the right one. i verified by doing a click on it.

Comment: @MalleshJM: I think you are not accessing the child checkboxes in your `element.all(by.model('result.dnb')).get(0)` I am sure there would be child checkboxes you have to put their attributes along with the parent one in your `element.all`

Comment: i can click on it with the same code without adding the attributes. there are no child check boxes that i can see. do you see any in the html above??